# Deploy Single Code Base To Multiple Clients

Tags: git, asp.net-core, teamcity, cicd

In my company there's an application repository that we would want to deploy to multiple clients. Each client have different application configuration values (*appsettings.json*) and this settings may change overtime depending on the clients. That is why, we create different git branches for each client in order to do CICD. There are multiple TeamCity Servers located in each client server (*on premise*) which are listening to their git branch for changes. Our concern is these number of clients will grow. The number of git branches will also increase and we do not want that to happen.

**Note**: Each client have their own staging and production environment. So we created the branch name as "clientA-staging", "clientA-production", "clientB-staging", "clientB-production". Another reason why we did this is because, if there is a changes in a client configuration. We just want to deploy this changes to that client only.

Are there any ways that we can improve this? What we want to achieve are:-

1. Reduce and maintain the number of staging and production git branches to two branches only.
2. Deploy to specific client only if there is configuration changes on their side.

Comment: What do you mean by if there is a changes in a client configuration ? Are you making change in code for that ?

Comment: Yup. Changes in code. To be specific. In appsettings.json

Comment: This is the case then things are complicated. Like till the time you make this changes there is a possibility that other client has some other changes or new development so when you actually apply this fix , you can not do that to main branch unless all your client ready to take that change. It seems like you have one product and than you are customizing it for specific scenario for client. This become problem and overhead in longer run for code but you have to see the business side as well.

Comment: I know what you mean. That is why we are trying to fix our mistakes. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve this by setting a comment filter in TeamCity (git commit message). By configuring the filter with for example "[clientA]", the deployment will only trigger if git comments matches the filter. In this case, it will only deploy to Client A.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue you faced, with one branch per customer, but that proved really painful as our customer base started to grow.
What we ended up doing was having a single branch for all customers (dev, staging, prod), and create an `appsettings.json` hierarchy:

```
appsettings.json                * config for all customers
  appsettings.Development.json  * config for all customers, for dev environment
  appsettings.Production.json   * config for all customers, for prod environment
  appsettings.client.json       * dummy file, just to have a proper hierarchy in VS
     appsettings.client.Customer1.json
        appsettings.client.Customer1.Development.json
        appsettings.client.Customer1.Production.json
     appsettings.client.Customer2.json
        appsettings.client.Customer2.Development.json
        appsettings.client.Customer2.Production.json
```

To load the proper appsettings for each customer, we use an environment variable, called `ASPNETCORE_CustomerName` (any variable prefixed with `ASPNETCORE_` will be loaded as an environment variable by the default web host builder) that we read when building the web host (in `Program.cs`):

```cs
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
    {
        return Host
            .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
                {
                    var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;

                    // read the customer name from the env variable
                    // (note that the ASPNETCORE_ prefix is removed)
                    var customer = hostingContext.Configuration.GetValue<string>("CustomerName");

                    // only add our custom hierarchy, 
                    // the default json files are already loaded
                    config
                        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.client.{customer}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.client.{customer}.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                        ;
                })
                .UseStaticWebAssets()
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
    }
}
```

Finally, we have one CI/CD pipeline per customer, and each customer webapp has its own `ASPNETCORE_CustomerName` variable set via the Azure portal.

Comment: Cool but how do you handle your CICD pipeline? With one branch for all the clients, isn't that will deploy to all of them?

Comment: It will indeed deploy all customers, but we don't consider a new deployment to be a costly operation, so we don't mind. Alternatively, you could add path filters to your CI/CD triggers, to only trigger if specific files are modified (e.g. for Azure yaml: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers).

Comment: I see.. Maybe there is no straight forward solution then.